# In the Dickinson Core Vocabulary why is vos given as an adjective, but tu as a pronoun?

Tags: dictionary

In the [Dickinson core vocabulary](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/latin-core-list1), they categorize the part of speech of *vos* as an adjective, but the singular *tu* as a pronoun. Is this just a typo in their database or is there some reason for the distinction? Note that both are listed as being in the pronoun "semantic category". It's only in the part of speech that they differ.

Answer (score 8):

Since [*nos*](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/latin-core/nos) (the closest comparator, along with *tu*, *ego* and so on) is classified as a pronoun, I think it is safe to conclude that it is an error in the database.

The [*vos*](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/latin-core/vos) entry is also irregular in that it contains the other cases (*vestrum* etc.) in the 'Definition' section rather than under the 'Headword' so I think it has probably been digitized sloppily.